# External JS loads multiple times

Tags: javascript, cdn

When JavaScript on my page is loaded from a CDN (or any external source) it loads multiple (5+) times. JS files that are local only load once.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<html>
  [...]

  <body>
    [...]

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the requests from Chrome's Resources tab:

[image: Chrome Resources]

As you can see, `bootstrap.min.js` (external) loads multiple times - but `bootstrap-notify.min.js` (local) loads once.

This happens with any external source, not only `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`.

EDIT:
Fixed it. It was a problem related to the AJAX requests in my JavaScript.

Comment: Does this happen on all browsers? Can you make a live demo?

Answer (score 1):

`$.fn.getPage` is your problem. You insert the *entire* HTML document into your current document, which will also insert the `<script>` tags.

Only replace the body:

```
$(data).find('body').children().appendTo(self.find('body').empty());
```

Comment: Ok! Fixed it. It was a problem with checking if current_page was undefined.